# Need help selecting a switch

Tags: power, current, switches, dc

I recently converted my bike to ebike that uses 36v (42v charged) lithium ion battery pack and taking it out and putting it back in makes a huge spark and the contacts are getting destroyed. Is there a switch i could install to cut the connection while im installing the battery then engage the switch once it is installed? bms Peak Discharge current : 50A. Continuous Discharge current : 30A. @ 42-36V DC. (this powers a 750w hub motor) I made a very crude home made handbrake type switch out of scrap metal that is complete overkill and want something better suited. I have observed that when I close the home made switch, it nearly welds the switch contacts together then if I break the circuit and use the switch again there is no more spark. If anyone have a solution to this would be great.

Comment: you can buy a battery cutoff switch for an automobile

Comment: why should there be a spark? ... are you not shutting down the system before disconnecting the battery?

Comment: Tony stewart (the answer below) did not really provide some details on his answer, but you should follow that. "Precharge" resistors are a thing and you should use them. One thing that I have with your issue though is, why do you have those sparks in the first place even though you don't have a load applied yet on those batteries?

Comment: Precharge resistors may be used rated for say 50W with the right value TBD. But ruggedized festoon  halogen tubes are also useful as indicators.  If it has a DCDC converter as well, these have a large surge current,

Comment: What brand of ESC do you have or not?

Comment: What I am using is a simple ebike conversion kit that connects the battery to a controller. The system is always turned OFF when I am connecting battery. The spark still damages the contacts when it is connected to the controller. Throttle and all accessories are turned off. I am not doing anything wrong and not putting any load on the battery while connecting it. Im not that stupid. But the solution provided is a bit too complex for me if there is a switch which can withstand 30-50A current at 42V is what I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: theres no actual brand. its like this https://www.ebay.com/itm/333354535901

Comment: MAYBE adding a series resistor in one lead during connection for a short while will work. It sounds as if either the controller is badly designed or faulty or that the connector is shorting. It MAY be that of you precharge with a resistopr then you will have a finite time during whoch discinnect then reconnect works OK. If so you could make an adaptor with series R, connect via adaptor, disconnect, reconnect without adaptor. How fast are your hands :-). You can test the time available by adding a temporary switch and seeing how long it can be ipen before the high current issue occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Using an oversized switch is not a solution for this kind of problem. At the input of the controller is probably a huge capacity what causes an initial current spike. To avoid it charge this capacity through 10 ohm power resistor (10W) and after charging short it with Pmos (or two in parallel to get 50A rating).

C2 and R7 is your ESC.

[image]

Blue is C2 voltage, Red is R6 charging current, Green is M1 current
[image]

You can see the charging current is 3.2A only so no spark on switch should be presented. 100ms after switch is closed the supplying of C2,R7 (ESC) is switched from R6 to M1 (direct connection Battery to ESC).

Q1 must be 60v Vce type at least, M1 -100v Vds like IRF9540N with 23A Id (parallel it or find one with higher current rating).

**Edit:**

If the circuit above is too complicated you can do the switching manually using three-pole switch.

At first pole is ESC disconnected from battery.
At second pole the ESC capacity is precharged through 10ohm (10W) resistor.
At third pole you make direct connection ESC to battery.

If you make a switch in this order it is safe because you cant do direct connection without precharge (second pole is sooner than third). Do the switching slow like in one second intervals.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is extremely complicated for me to understand or make any use of this. Thank you for all your dedication and work.

Comment: Would be nice to find these already built on ebay so one can just pick one up and use it

Comment: would putting in 10w 1k ohms resistor with secondary switch suffice? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BT8QcExOWSo the way this guy did it?

Comment: The single ICL in my answer replaces this circuit.

Comment: already ordered https://www.ebay.com/itm/254294650019 from this seller 10w at 1k ohms by mistake. i emailed the guy to correct the order but Chinese don't always understand

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will prevent the connection arc.  Since the switches won't be used during operation of the ESC, only to all the ESC caps to charge up, I suspect a 30A switch will be enough for SW1 and SW2 rating depends on lamp used to charge up ESC caps.  1mF is not the actual value, but it's big enough to weld your contacts. I recall once having computer grade 100mF to do this welding at 63V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE6Usy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The lamp is for a quick and dirty test and is a PTC.  The proper solution is an NTC or a negative temp coefficient metal oxide resistor than drops in resistance to 1% of the cold value after the load cap charges up. They are also use to extend life on halogen and incandescent lamps and reduce surge current in motors.

If the tungsten lamp is 5 Ohms cold and rated for 120V or 240V, it will be 50 Ohms hot   \$Pd=V^2/R_{hot}\$  This will not get very hot with only 50V but will still cause a spark but reduce the current so you can measure the load voltage during the process to measure the capacitance from the rise time. C= T/R(avg) for T = 63 % of 50V or 33V . Just a ballpark measure is needed.

https://www.ametherm.com/datasheetspdf/SL3210015.pdf
Digikey has them in different sizes.

Comment: Looking over the schematic, I realize your proposition. This could be a good idea just wish this would be more compact to implement.

Comment: any suggestions how i should go about estimating the load capacitance? i have no idea how much power the controller draws. i have no equipment but a very basic voltmeter at my disposal measures ohms and amps with 2 probes.

Comment: would 10w 1k ohms resistor suffice? the same way this guy did it? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BT8QcExOWSo

Comment: You can easily test it with a 60W light bulb and measure the time to reach 50V after the bulb and measure the resistance.  I suggest getting 2 of the ICL's in my answer. 10 ohms cold , 0.1 Ohms hot  that's a 5 Amps surge rather than a 50 A surge. You can use 2 in series if your test reaches 50V, quickly otherwise not. Or get a higher R ICL.  That what these are for, as long as the steady current is less than the rating.

Answer (score 0):

A solution which doesn't address your actual problem, is not a switch. It's relays. You can make a small circuit with a regulator down to 12 or 24V for the coils and common automotive power relays. If you can't find 50A relays then 2 30A relays in parallel would work. Then you use a simple switch to turn them on.

Finding out why your battery pack is arcing on removal or insertion would be better. Use an ammeter or a current shunt to get an idea on what the actual current is while everything is powered off.

Comment: i am sure its arcing because the controller itself consumes a very small amount of energy even though motor and all accessories are off. ill have to look into relays and how they work in order to put this solution to a test

Comment: @lance "a very small amount of energy" is usually not enough to visibly arc or eat away at contacts like that. You don't normally see usb or DC connections arcing and those can get up to 65W or higher.

Comment: from what i read online there are capacitors in the controller that need to be charged. the capacity is unknown and im not about to take it apart to check. going the route of what others have done in this case with a 10w resistor to pre-charge the controller

Comment: The thing about capacitors are that they charge up and stop. Unless they start getting drained. A visible spark indicates an active power drain.